# Reference field outside the subgroup (Unknown column in where clause)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I am trying to reference the **a.pointer** inside a subquery but it looks like mysql doesn't allow to reference fields outside a subquery.

```
UPDATE order_items AS a

SET a.id_parent = (

SELECT id FROM((

select id from order_items as b where (b.pointer = a.pointer) and (b.id_parent = 0)) 

)x) 

WHERE a.id_parent > 9999
```

What is the best way to access the a.pointer inside the subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do a self join here; something like

```
UPDATE order_items a 
    JOIN order_items b ON b.pointer = a.pointer AND b.id_parent = 0
SET a.id_parent = b.id
WHERE a.id_parent > 9999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a join for this

```
UPDATE order_items as a
SET a.id_parent = b.id    
JOIN(select id from order_items as c where  c.id_parent = 0) b ON b.pointer = a.pointer
WHERE a.id_parent > 9999
```

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM order_items AS a
JOIN(select id from order_items as b where b.id_parent = ' at line 3

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN (select id from order_items as b where b.id_parent = 0) ON b.pointer = a.po' at line 3

Comment: As far as I know JOIN requires a table name not a number (ID in this case). Doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  a
SET a.id_parent = b.id
from order_items a join order_items b 
on (a.pointer = b.pointer )
where b.id_parent = 0 and a.id_parent > 9999
```

You can use self join as above .

Thanks